# Detect timestamp and make them clickable in texts with React Native, like what youtube does

Tags: react-native, timestamp

I need to detect links and timestamps in text. The links I can already identify and click with help from the [react-native-autolink](https://github.com/joshswan/react-native-autolink) library.
In the case of timestamps, I need to identify in the following formats:

'00:00',
'0:00',
'00:00:00',
'0:00:00'

With the help of the [react-string-replace](https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace) library, I was able to turn one of the timestamps into a Text tag and so click, but I did it manually and it's duplicating. my goal is to let all the timestamps clickable to make an audio player jump to the time that was clicked.Like what youtube does.

Repository link [Detect-Timestamp-In-Text](https://github.com/Warlen27/Detect-Timestamp-In-Text/blob/master/src/App.js)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmo69.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the intermediary `funcTime` function is not necessary - just update your regex for timestamps to `/(\d+:\d+:?\d+)/g`, and use `replaceTime` on the passed in content portion like so:

```
const replaceTime = useCallback(
  text => {
    return reactStringReplace(text, /(\d+:\d+:?\d+)/g, (match, i) => (
      <Text
        key={i.toString()}
        onPress={() => Alert.alert('Deu certo')}
        style={{ color: '#f00' }}
      >
        {match}
      </Text>
    ));
  },
  [content_snippet],
);

// and call it in the AutoLink component:

renderText={replaceTime}
```